# Flutter notification with django channels

Tags: django, flutter, sockets, django-models, websocket

Please explain me how can i implement flutter notification with django channel socket
. I am not getting any idea to connect flutter to the django socket channel for notification .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This mechanism is some complicated,
Why not use from FCM?